# Class not serializing as expected

Tags: c#, serialization

I've been struggling with this all day. I done a lot of research, but I just can't seem to put it all together.

I have a XML response from a server like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<inboxRecords>
    <inboxRecord>
        <field1 />
        <field2 />
        <field3 />
    </inboxRecord>
    <inboxRecord>
        <field1 />
        <field2 />
        <field3 />
    </inboxRecord>
</inboxRecords>
```

I created the following code to represent the response. The intention is that I will de-serialize the response using the following:

```
[XmlRoot("inboxRecords")]
public sealed class QueueQueryResult
{
    public InboxRecord[] InboxRecords;

    public QueueQueryResult()
    {
        InboxRecords = null;
    }

    public sealed class InboxRecord
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The classes above are based on one of the numerous examples I found online. The problem is, when I serialize the class above (to confirm that it is correct), it comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<inboxRecords>
  <InboxRecords>
    <InboxRecord>
      <field1>some value</field1>
    </InboxRecord>
    <InboxRecord>
      <field1>some value</field1>
    </InboxRecord>
  </InboxRecords>
</inboxRecords>
```

So, first problem, how do I get rid of the extra InboxRecords element? I only want the root to say that (with a small 'i'). Second, for quick testing, I only put a value in the first field. Why didn't the other fields come out as empty elements? Do I need another decorator for that?

Thanks!
Thanks!

Comment: Your nested class is called InboxRecord ... thats what the serializer will use.

Comment: Have you tried using `xsd.exe` to generate the class for you?

Comment: I did and the class it generated doesn't seem that different from what I already have. I haven't added the class to my project yet, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `XmlElement` attribute:

```
[XmlRoot("inboxRecords")]
public sealed class QueueQueryResult
{
    [XmlElement("inboxRecord")]
    public InboxRecord[] InboxRecords;

    public QueueQueryResult()
    {
        InboxRecords = null;
    }

    public sealed class InboxRecord
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This removes the Array wrapper element and allows you to control the name for each xml element so that you can use lower case names.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I knew I was close.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I reckon you could probably do something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("inboxRecords")]
public sealed class QueueQueryResult : Collection<QueueQueryResult.InboxRecord>
{
    public QueueQueryResult()
    {
        InboxRecords = null;
    }

    public sealed class InboxRecord
    {
        public string field1 { get; set; }
        public string field2 { get; set; }
        public string field3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that you've got a member `InboxRecords` within an object that is serialising to `inboxRecords`. By making the class inherit from `Collection`, you're providing it with the capability to handle a set of `InboxRecords` without the extra inner element.

Comment: I actually did it your way, too, and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After generating an XSD from your first sample XML (and then a .cs) using `xsd.exe`, I can create and serialize an instance from your second example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<inboxRecords xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <inboxRecord>
    <field1>some value</field1>
  </inboxRecord>
  <inboxRecord>
    <field1>some value</field1>
  </inboxRecord>
</inboxRecords>
```

With the exception of the encoding attribute and the schema namespace, this looks pretty darn similar to the first sample.